# MvxListItemView migration from MvvmCross 4.2.3 to 5.1.1

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am currently upgrading my app to use the latest version of MvvmCross (5.1.1). It was previously using 4.2.3.

The only problem I have encountered so far is with a class derived from MvxListItemView.

In my code I have an adaptor for my CustomListItemView. In the GetView override in my adaptor I attempt to cast the View passed in, to my CustomListItemView type e.g

```
public overrride View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView is CustomListItemView)
    {
        // do something
        CustomListItemView myCustomListItemView = (CustomListItemView) convertView;
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

I get the following error

```
Cannot convert type 'Android.Views.View' to 'MyNameSpace.CustomListItemView'
```

Also if I try to use FindViewById in my CustomListItemView it says

```
'CustomListItemView' does not contain a definition for 'FindViewById'
```

This used to work in 4.2.3

It's as if MvxListView is no longer derived from View.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The MvxListView in MvvmCross 5.x, I think also late 4.x versions uses the ViewHolder pattern. So MvxListViewItem has gone from being a View to now being a ViewHolder.

So instead of inflating your own view etc, you want to do something like this instead:

```
public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
{
    public CustomAdapter(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext) : base(context, bindingContext)
    {
    }

    public CustomAdapter(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, ViewGroup parent, int templateId)
    {
        if (dataContext is ViewModelA)
        {
            templateId = Resouce.Layout.item_a;
        }
        else if (dataContext is ViewModelB)
        {
            templateId = Resouce.Layout.item_b;
        }

        return base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, parent, templateId);
    }
}
```

The built in `base.GetBindableView` will then take care of the rest, if the `convertView` is the wrong template it creates a new ViewHolder etc.

Comment: Thanks @Cheesebaron, I'll see if I can apply this to my existing app.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not getting how this is supposed to work. Do I not override GetView anymore? If not I don't understand why not. Whay should I do differently when creating a custom MvxListItemView. Is there an example of using the new MvxListItemView I could follow?

Comment: return new MvxListItemView(_context, _bindingContext.LayoutInflaterHolder, dataContext, templateId);

Compile time error here and is expecting ViewGroup?